# How to display mysql dynamic query on jsp page

Tags: mysql, jsp, dynamic, pivot

I have a mysql query that dynamically creates a pivot table.

[you can see the screen shot of out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTtYn.jpg)
How can I display this generated pivot table on jsp page dynamically.  I tried flowing code but it returns a error on eclipse it says ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data. Your help is appreciated.

```
public String getSaymanRaporu() throws SQLException {
    String out = "\n";    
    Connection connection = null;
    try {

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUserName, dbPassword);
        Statement stm = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
        String sql = "HERE COME SQL CODE";
        System.out.println("rapor sql:"+sql);
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);

        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        for(int i = 1; i<= numberOfColumns; i++){
            out.concat(metaData.getColumnName(i));
        }
        out.concat("\n");

        if(rs.next()){
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++){
                out.concat((String) rs.getObject(i));
            }
            out.concat("\n");

        rs.close();

        stm.close();

        connection.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return "error";
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                System.out.println(ignore.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("out:"+out);
    return out;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add Java code into JSP pages with <% %> tag. For example:

```
<div>
<head>
<title>Java into JSP</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <%
            //Java code
            String var = "It works";
        %>
        <div>
            <%=var%>
        </div>
    </body>
</div>
```

I think this gives you an idea of how to do what you need.